# Which performance testing tool should be used to test the Informatica customer 360 portal (HP Loadrunner / JMeter)

Tags: performance-testing

I want to test the Informatica customer 360 UI portal w.r.t load / endurance / stress testing,  can you please suggest which performance testing tools supports the Informatica Customer 360 UI / Portal.  If in case both tools (HP Loadrunner as well as JMeter support it what is the protocol which should be used for recording the script and which tool is the best for this scenario).  If there is some other tool which supports, kindly list that as well.

Many thanks in advance. Let me know if any more details are required to answer the question effectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to load test the web interface - both tools will fit as both support [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol including recording.

With regards to the choice:

- LoadRunner:

  - On one hand LoadRunner is a proprietary load testing tool so you might get benefit from their [support](https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/services/maintenance-and-support-plans)
  - On the other hand LoadRunner is paid tool, 50 virtual users you get for free, the next ones [cost $1.40 per virtual user per day](https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/products/loadrunner-load-testing/pricing)
  - Although LoadRunner provides record and replay features most probably you will need to write some code in [C language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) and not very modern standard without any access to extra libraries like [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)
- JMeter

  - is free and open source, however the support is limited to [mailing list](https://jmeter.apache.org/mail.html) and [community forums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter)
  - you don't need to know programming languages as it's possible to create tests using JMeter GUI

So if you have license (or budget) and not afraid of C programming - go for LoadRunner, theoretically you will have better support and get recording of more protocols out of the box

If you would rather prefer to save funds - stick to JMeter (or other [free and open source load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use/)) given it supports the [network protocol(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) which are used by the application you're going to test.